# Upload and rename multiple files to FTP using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, ftp

We are creating CMS, in which we want to have the option to upload multiple files to FTP server. The steps are

1. Open FTP connection
2. Click browse - Select multiple files - Click upload to FTP
3. Create a folder on the FTP server
4. Rename the selected files and upload them to the folder
5. Close the connection

It will be good if it shows the status of the upload.

We are using asp.net with C#. Any sample code will help. Is there any good components available. I can spend max of $150 to buy a component.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you start something like *"We are creating a CMS..."* **something is wrong**! with so many open source CMS's out there (and in .NET) why creating a new one? **why not contribute** and update the existing ones?

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all, you should use an open source CMS and improve the code to your needs, don't try to reinvent the wheel!

**Second**, there is no need to spend money, plenty of solutions out there ...

you can use, for example [**Uploadify**](http://www.uploadify.com/) to pass user files to your server, then using any [FTP Example](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/080327.htm) upload the files to the FTP and delete them from the server upon success.

if you don't want to have the "middle men", just upload directly to the FTP

```
string name = Path.GetFileName(UploadControl.FileName);
byte[] data = UploadControl.FileBytes;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
   client.UploadData("ftp://my.ftp.server.com/myfolder/" + name, data);
}
```

Comment: Hello, We need to upload thousands of files to ftp server every single day. By uploading first to own server and then to ftp location requires double the time and bandwidth. We prefer to have direct upload to the ftp server from client. Thank you.